# Does Unity Remote 4 act the same as it would when it is on the app store?

Tags: c#, iphone, mobile, unity-game-engine

I am using the app Unity Remote 4 to test my app that I am developing. I am wondering if how the app works on Unity Remote will be the exact same as it would if it was on the app store. I am asking this because In my code i have Input.GetAxis("Fire1") and when I tap the screen Input.GetAxis("Fire1") returns 1, and in the input manager it says its only assigned to return 1 when it is clicked by a mouse.

When i tap the screen, is it just registering as a click event, or does the input manager treat touches and clicks as the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of them may work on mobile but it is not reliable and NOT recommended. If you want to read the touch screen on mobile devices, avoid things like **Input.GetMouseButtonDown**,  **Input.GetAxis("Fire1")**. These are made for **mouse** and **keyboards** for **Standalone builds**.

For mobile devices, use **(Input.touchCount > 0) && (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)** to detect when a finger is on the screen, **Touch.deltaPosition** to check how fast the finger is finger is moving on the screen.

For single, tap, double tap ore more, use **Touch.tapCount**.

Now, to answer your **Unity Remote** question, the use of **Unity Remote** is **ONLY** to speed up the developing and testing process so that you don't have to upload your app each time to the mobile device to test it. It works fine but there are few problems. The things that are quiet different between using **Unity Remote** and running it on your mobile device is the float values returned from the screen such as **Touch.deltaPosition.magnitude**.  They will work on your PC with **Unity Remote** but wont be the expected values you expect your mobile **device**.

For example, when you have a code like this:

```
float moveThreshold = 20;
if ((Touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) && (Touch.deltaPosition.magnitude > moveThreshold)){
destroyEnemy();
}
```

Assuming this worked on your PC with Unity Remote during developing, it may **NOT** work on your mobile device after you decide to test it on a mobile device. So, your final game will end up with many enemies because the enemies did not destroy. Adjusting the **moveThreshold** to 5 or 4 will fix it. Although, it **worked on PC** but **NOT** on a **mobile platform**.

You **must** **test** it on a **physical device** before even thinking about releasing your game. That's the fact and I have been there before.